# Getting street names in iOS

Tags: ios, autocomplete, geolocation, location, mkmapview

I need to offer users a way to type an address in an `UITextField` with an autocompletion functionality as user is introducing the text. I've been looking for the best way to implement this, but I'm still not sure: is it possible to get a list of street names for a certain city? Or should I being provided such information in another and custom way (service request, a file with that information...)?

My application is for iOS 7+

Thanks

Comment: you have to add each city street address in database and after got it.

Comment: Use google places API..https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

Comment: @KrunalDarji Thanks. What about `MKLocalSearch`? I've never used it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using Google Places autocomplete API.This api provide you addreess that you want in list.

For More info please refer this example that help you to how to use Google Places autocomplete with your application

https://maniacdev.com/2013/10/ios-completion-providing-search-with-autocompletion-and-map-marking-using-google-places

you can find sample code for the same on Github find Below link for this

https://github.com/chenyuan/SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you know if `MKLocalSearch` offers the same functionality as `Google Places API`?

Comment: yes,MKLocalSearch is also useful it would be introduces in ios 6.0. you can use it too.I am not sure how much it accurate in reference to Google Place autocomplete API Because never used MKLocalSearch.You can find  below Example link that may help you for MKLocalSearch. https://github.com/iamamused/Example-MKLocalSearch

Comment: MKLocalSearch          http://jeffreysambells.com/2013/01/28/mklocalsearch-example                                                          stack overflow this link also help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798804/use-mklocalsearch-to-search-for-locations-on-a-map